# how to parse json based on index number of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have data in json format where I need to access the data contained in each object within the array. So for example, If I need the timestamp in the second object (which is "202103092000") what would my syntax need to be to to assign the value of "period" in the second object to the stated var?  I have tried variations of this approach but it does not seem to work:

```
var data4 = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
fcperiod2 = data4.[1].period;
```

The json data beeing parsed would be as follows. I don't have control over how it is formatted as it is coming in from an api.

```
[{
    "period": "202103092000",
    "condition": "A mix of sun and cloud",
    "temperature": "0",
    "icon_code": "02",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092100",
    "condition": "Mainly sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "01",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092200",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092300",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "3",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}]
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Baobab

Comment: Are you sure that the element's position in the collection remains the same each time it is loaded?

Comment: It is still an array. You don't put a . before the index. 

data4.[1].period should be data4[1].period

Comment: Shouldn't it data4[1]. period?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Such a simple mistake and I wasted a good two hours on it - clearly coding is not my thing. As far as asking the question with a minimal reproducible example, I think what I provided is exactly that. I even took the time to learn what the different parts of a json object are called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still an array so you wouldn't access it as a property with .[4] you would say to grab the X element of the actual array by saying data4[X].period

TLDR; **replace data4.[1] with data4[1].period**

```js
let message = { payloadString: [{
    "period": "202103092000",
    "condition": "A mix of sun and cloud",
    "temperature": "0",
    "icon_code": "02",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092100",
    "condition": "Mainly sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "01",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092200",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092300",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "3",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}]
}

var data4 = message.payloadString;
fcperiod2 = data4[1].period;
console.log(fcperiod2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with several [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). You get the object at a position in the array just with `data4[1]`. To get the value for the key `period`, you can use `data4[1].period`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the periods and then later decide which one you want

```js
const data = [{
    "period": "202103092000",
    "condition": "A mix of sun and cloud",
    "temperature": "0",
    "icon_code": "02",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092100",
    "condition": "Mainly sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "01",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092200",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "2",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}, {
    "period": "202103092300",
    "condition": "Sunny",
    "temperature": "3",
    "icon_code": "00",
    "precip_probability": "0"
}]
const periods = data.map(({period}) => period)
console.log(periods)
console.log(periods[1])
```